# user with recent posts will return results much faster then users with older ones

Tags: mysql, sql

> user 1 has post ids: 2,5,7,9
>
> user 2 has post ids:600000, 600020, 600025, 600033

My table posts has 600050 rows.

That is the problem, if I'd like to select posts from user 1 it will take 15.+ seconds and if I want to select posts from user 2 it will finished in 0,0005.

I notice that users with more recent posts will load much faster.

user 1:

```
select c.nome from posts p 
join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 

where (p.user in (1)) and p.delete='0' 
//p.user in 1 - if I place to 2 it will get results much faster

group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit ?
```

I'd like to get results faster from both. not only user 2.
any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `titulo` text,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20),
  `delete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I tried to add index on user, but nothing has changed.

Comment: It really sounds like a missing index on `user`, possibly also `delete`. 1) Please show us the output of `explain` with that statement. 2) `user` should be declared as a foreign key, then it will automatically get an index. 3) Try putting an index on `delete` as well. 4) (Side note) Mixing languages in a schema will hamper readability, go with one or the other.

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` rather than `GROUP BY` for cases like this; I can't say it will make it any faster, but makes the intent of the query a little clearer, which is helpful to anyone who has to modify the query in the future, and can help MySQL make better decisions about how to handle things. _(Though sometimes misuse like this can help too.)_

Comment: Just to be sure, `cadastro` is indexed on `id`, right? _Also, it'd probably be helpful if you added its CREATE to the question as well... example: if `cadastro.id` is a different type and needs cast, that could cause some performance issues even if it were indexed._

Comment: @Uueerdo cadastro has a primary key: id, auto_increment.

Comment: As ueerdo says, in the absence of any aggregating functions, don't use a group by clause. While it may outperform distinct, the results returned could well be misleading

Comment: @RickJoe and it is `int`; not `tinyint`, `smallint`, `mediumint`, or `bigint`?

Comment: @Uueerdo it is `int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: It's reaching at this point, but some more ideas.... (1) what type is `nome`? is it possible you are just getting significantly large amounts of data? (2) have you checked disk fragmentation?

Comment: @Uueerdo nome is varchar. I have about 600.000 rows on table posts, 100.000 rows on table cadastro, but I think it isn't that much. I add some foreign keys and it helped, not much, but helped.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an index on `user`, so you're going to have to do a table scan each time to find posts. This is capital B **Bad** and will cripple performance. Fix it with:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_user ON posts (user, `delete`);
```

Then you can check with `EXPLAIN` to ensure it's applied correctly on your query.

As a note, try and avoid using [MySQL reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) like `DELETE` as column names. Something similar like "deleted" works just as well.

Comment: strange, with this index it is taking 25.1831 seconds.

Comment: To create the index, or to run the query with the index?

Comment: to run the query with the index.

Comment: Try getting rid of the strange `GROUP BY` part, simplify the query, to see if it speeds up at some point. Always check with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see how MySQL interprets it. Seeing "table scan" means you've got big problems.